# Xcode Build server. Git operation failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, osx-server, build-server

I've got an error on my Build server. It looks like this:

> Bot Issue for My OSX Project (build service error)
>
> Integration #1300 of My OSX Project
>
> Open in Xcode: xcbot://xwserver/botID/d127cd23bd4cee1081dfcc192904a85b/integrationID/699d47fa9105419469cca90c6a2a7286
>
> Assertion: Could not open '/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/d127cd23bd4cee1081dfcc192904a85b/Source/xwrtrunk/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/AnotherProjectFolderName'
>
> for writing: Is a directory (-1) File: (null):(null)
>
> Introduced 5 integrations ago
>
> Full logs for this integration are attached.

When I changed git repo, everything was great. but with this git repo it always fail. And I don't know what I must do. And even no ideas.

What did we do:

- Cut checkouted repo on build server
- Checked file system using disc utilities.

P.S. Any way thanks for attention.

Comment: What version of XCode and git are you using? Did you try to clone that repo again (outside of XCode) and point XCode to that copy to see if that helps avoiding this issue?

Comment: git version 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63). Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175). El Capitan 10.11.2 (15C50). We tried to use another repo and everything was great. But we need to use this because it is our working repo with a "long history".

Comment: Could you clone again that repo, and make XCode point to it? The clone would have the exact same history.

Comment: We got this problem when I created a branch folder, which name was equal to folder name in the repo. We just deleted this branch and everything is great at the moment.

Comment: We found this solution when were trying to clone repo. So your advice was really helpful. May you give an answer bellow for bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a repo is problematic with XCode, the first workaround is to:

- clone it again.
- Make XCode reference the newly cloned repo

The [OP ZevsVU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401067/zevsvu) (doing just that) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577621/xcode-build-server-git-operation-failed/36647381#comment60887673_36577621):

> We got this problem when I **created a branch folder which name was equal to folder name in the repo**.
> We just deleted this branch and everything is great at the moment.

---

Another instance of a similar issue is now (Q4 2021) better presented:

See [commit 66e905b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66e905b7dd0f4e9dd576be681f30fbaeeb19ec4a), [commit a7439d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7439d0f9dd291e7cc9e6c2dda19cbfdf09b62ee) (25 Aug 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7b06222](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b062226196c7234818106ab5274b32519e41575), 08 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`xopen`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7439d0f9dd291e7cc9e6c2dda19cbfdf09b62ee): explicitly report creation failures
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> If the flags `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` are both given then open(2) is supposed to create the file and error out if it already exists.
> The error message in that case looks like this:
>
> ```
> fatal: could not open 'foo' for writing: File exists
> ```
>
> Without further context this is confusing: Why should the existence of the file pose a problem?  Isn't that a requirement for writing to it?
>
> Add a more specific error message for that case to tell the user that we actually don't expect the file to preexist, so the example becomes:
>
> ```
> fatal: unable to create 'foo': File exists
> ```

Comment: Thanks for attention.